# Can you access the previous value of a ndb property in _pre_put_hook?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an ndb model as follows:

```
class SomeModel(ndb.Model):     
    name = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    valid = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)

def some_function():
    print "fired"
```

When the name property is changed from what it was previously I would like the `some_function()` function to fire.

e.g.

```
$ q = SomeModel.query().get()
$ print p.name 
John
$ q.name = "Sam"
$ q.put()
"fired"
```

If, however the valid property is changed say from `False` to `True` I do not want `some_function()` to fire.

e.g.

```
$ q = SomeModel.query().get()
$ print p.name
Sam
$ print p.valid 
False
$ q.valid = True
$ q.put()
```

With using either `_post_put_hook` or `_pre_put_hook` is there a way to access the previous value of the property so I can optionally fire or not fire an external function?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without running another query.  And, since you've already done the query outside the model, it would be less expensive to just use that: `if q.name != new_name: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach has always seemed a bit hacky to me, but it seems to work.

You can store the attribute values on the instance in the `_post_get_hook`, and retrieve them in the `_pre_put_hook` (or the `_post_put_hook`):

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):

    ...

    @classmethod
    def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
        instance = future.get_result()
        if instance:
            # Store 'old' instance data as an instance attribute
            instance._before = instance.to_dict()

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        # Check if our storage attribute exists,
        # this could be a new instance.
        if hasattr(self, '_before'):
            # Do something with 'before' data
            ...
            # clean up
            del self._before
```

#### Edit:

Cleaning up - deleting the storage attribute may require some thought if you are going to call `put` on your object more than once.  For standard models you could leave the attribute in place, but this could be a problem with Expando models, as the attribute will be written to the datastore.